# Go & PHP socket communication

Tags: php, sockets, go

I have created a connection between a PHP script and Go with the following code:

> Go (server):

```
ln, err1 := net.Listen("tcp", ":5432")
if err1 != nil{
    fmt.Println(err1.Error())
    return
}
conn, err2 := ln.Accept()
if err2 != nil{
    fmt.Println(err2.Error())
    return
}

buf := make([]byte, 11)
_, err3:= conn.Read(buf)
if err3 != nil{
    fmt.Println(err3.Error())
    return
}
fmt.Println(string(buf))

_, err := conn.Write([]byte("HELLO WORLD"))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
}
```

> PHP (Client):

```
$address = gethostbyaddr("localhost"); 
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

if($socket === false){
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
}

$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, 5432); 
if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
} 

if($socket!==false && $result!==false)
    echo "ok";

socket_write($socket, "hello world", 11); 
fflush($socket);
if($out = socket_read($socket, 4)){ 
    echo $out;
}
```

I can connect and receive "hello world" on the Go server. 
 
**Problem:** When I try to send something back to PHP. All I get is "*invalid argument*" at `_, err := conn.Write([]byte(msg + "\n"))`.

Comment: you go  code is full of build error  
no new variables on left side of :=,
 undefined: msg,
readlen declared and not used
FIX THE BUILD ERROR

Comment: PHP is probably closing the socket after exiting. What happens if you add `socket_set_block($socket);` before the write and `sleep(60);` at the end of your PHP script?

Comment: What's the output of `go env` and `go version`?